# Wordpress xmlrpc.php 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean, xml-rpc, jetpack

I have a site setup on Digital Ocean using their Wordpress droplet installer. I have then installed Jetpack.

The Site Health tool reported that Jetpack is not connected and that I should visit the Jetpack.com debugger.  I did so and put my website in. The error I get:

```
XML-RPC is not responding correctly ( 200 )
```

When visiting the url `mywebaddress.com/xmlrpc.php` I just get redirected to the main URL of the site.

As recommended by Jetpack I went to a terminal and ran

```
curl -A 'Jetpack by WordPress.com' -d '<methodCall><methodName>demo.sayHello</methodName></methodCall>' https://mywebaddress.com/xmlrpc.php
```

When I do so I get the following coming back.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://mywebaddress.com/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at mywebaddress.com Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

I have checked the `.htaccess` file and this contains only comments. 
I have checked `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and can find no redirects there.

So my question is, can anyone tell me what might be causing this 301 Redirect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer
I have just located this file:

`/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/block-xmlrpc.conf`

This had this inside

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <Directory / >
        Redirect 301 /xmlrpc.php /
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

This file was causing the redirect. Have commented out its contents for now. 
I didn't create this, so I must assume DigitalOcean create it when doing the Wordpress one click install

Comment: Your assumption is correct, the one-click for wordpress says the following: Disables XML-RPC to help prevent DDoS and other brute force attacks.

Comment: @Zoomulator how can one not enable this, but still have Jetpack running? 

Disables XML-RPC to help prevent DDoS and other brute force attacks....

Comment: @Mark have you experienced any problem since editing the file

Comment: @JosephWambura I have not.

Comment: Thanks. Lemme comment mine too

Answer (score 0):

I found this file under /etc/apache2/conf-available/ rather than /conf-enabled/